# Error subquery uses ungrouped (columns correlation)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Recently I tried to create a query to obtain some statistical data, but I got this error:

> subquery uses ungrouped column "vegetacionpotencial.ident" from outer query

```
select 
  veg_pot
  , sum(hauvg)
  ,(
     select 
       sum(hadef) 
     from tematica.vegetacionpotencial v, tematica.deforestacion d 
       join estados on (vegetacionpotencial.ident=estados.ident) 
     where 
       st_covers(v.geom,d.geom) and estado = 'Yucatán'
   ) 
from tematica.vegetacionpotencial
  join estados on (vegetacionpotencial.ident=estados.ident)
where 
  estado = 'Yucatán' 
group by 
  veg_pot
```

Comment: Please learn to format your code. Show your table definitions and perhaps go to SQL fiddle and insert minimal data to show us your problem.

Comment: If you don't provide table definitions (which would be best), you must at least table-qualify all columns in use to give us a fighting chance to interpret your query. And please *always* provide your version of Postgres. Of course, there should also be some explanation as to what the query is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Your original query formatted but otherwise unchanged:

```
SELECT veg_pot, sum(hauvg)
     ,(SELECT sum(hadef) 
       FROM   tematica.vegetacionpotencial v
            , tematica.deforestacion d 
       JOIN   estados ON (vegetacionpotencial.ident = estados.ident) 
       WHERE  st_covers(v.geom, d.geom)
       AND    estado = 'Yucatán') 
FROM   tematica.vegetacionpotencial
JOIN   estados ON (vegetacionpotencial.ident = estados.ident)
WHERE  estado = 'Yucatán' 
GROUP  BY veg_pot;
```

Since you added the column alias `v` to `tematica.vegetacionpotencial` in the correlated subquery, the original table name is not visible any more. To refer3ence the table (like it seems you want to) you must use the visible alias `v`.

After checking visible identifiers in the inner query, Postgres extends the scope to the next outer query level and finds `vegetacionpotencial` there. Howev er, the column `ident` is not grouped in outer query, which leads to the logic error you got:

> subquery uses ungrouped column "vegetacionpotencial.ident" from outer query

You can fix the error, but the query is ***still no good***:

```
SELECT veg_pot, sum(hauvg)
     ,(SELECT sum(hadef) 
       FROM   tematica.vegetacionpotencial v1
       JOIN   estados e ON v1.ident = e.ident
            , tematica.deforestacion d 
       WHERE  st_covers(v.geom, d.geom)
       AND    estado = 'Yucatán') 
FROM   tematica.vegetacionpotencial v
JOIN   estados ON vegetacionpotencial.ident = estados.ident
WHERE  estado = 'Yucatán' 
GROUP  BY veg_pot, v.geom;
```

Proper information is missing, but going out on a limb, my educated guess is you might want something like this instead:

```
SELECT veg_pot, sum(hauvg) AS sum_hauvg
    , (SELECT sum(hadef)
       FROM   tematica.deforestacion d 
       WHERE  st_covers(v.geom, d.geom)) AS sum_hadef
FROM   estados e
JOIN   tematica.vegetacionpotencial v USING (ident)
WHERE  e.estado = 'Yucatán'
GROUP  BY veg_pot, v.geom;
```